# How to stop AnythingSlider on the final slide?

Tags: jquery, slider

How can I make the slider stop playing once it reaches the final slide? It's [this slider here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/).

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry, there's loads of "sliders" out there. Some relate to input controls and others relate to content thumbnails that move around etc. You will need to provide a link to the specific slider you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian's answer was almost spot on. The only change needed was to base.$items.length()-1

The correct code, for anyone who might want to use it, is:

```
base.goForward = function(autoplay){
    if(autoplay !== true) autoplay = false;
    if(autoplay && base.currentPage == base.pages) {
        base.startStop(false); // stops auto play
        return;
    }
    base.gotoPage(base.currentPage + 1, autoplay);
};
```

Comment: It would have been appreciated if you could have left an upvote for a near complete solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for stopping the auto play on the last slide. I don't have the time just now to make an example but it looks like you can ammend the js file to stop the autoplay after the last slide.

In line number 136 of the js file, replace the existing function with the following:

```
base.goForward = function(autoplay){
if(autoplay !== true) autoplay = false;

if(autoplay && base.currentPage == base.$items.length()-1) {
base.startStop(false); // stops auto play
return;
}
base.gotoPage(base.currentPage + 1, autoplay);
};
```

I can't test this just now but it shouldn't be far away from your requirement.

Comment: The library has been updated since this answer to have this feature built in: https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/issues/94